# Codeigniter 3.x - Left join and displaying field problems

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to display ALL blogs regardless of whether there are comments associated with it or not BUT I have 1 problem as these are as follows:

1. Not all fields from the COMMENTS TABLE and ENTRY TABLE are displayed (seems like if there is a duplicate field name it is not displayed, however, as you can see, I use the full field names eg. tablename.fieldname)

Here is my MODEL:

class A_User_Blog_Comments_model extends CI_Model {

```
public function get_blog($id) {
        $this->db->select('
            entry.user_id,
            entry.entry_id,
            entry.entry_name,
            entry.entry_body,
            entry.status,
            entry.created_timestamp,
            entry.updated_timestamp,
            comments.id,
            comments.comment,
            comments.user_id,
            comments.blog_id,
            comments.status,
            comments.created_timestamp,
            comments.updated_timestamp
        ');
        $this->db->from('entry'); 
        $this->db->join('comments', 'entry.entry_id=comments.blog_id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('entry.entry_id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        if($query->num_rows() != 0)
        {
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
 }
```

Here is a simple dump in my view file:

```
 Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 1
        [entry_id] => 1
        [entry_name] => twkla nnn xxx
        [entry_body] => this is just UPDATED
        [status] => active
        [created_timestamp] => 2017-01-03 00:00:00
        [updated_timestamp] => 2017-01-04 00:00:00
        [id] => 1
        [comment] => This is a comment
        [blog_id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 1
        [entry_id] => 1
        [entry_name] => twkla nnn xxx
        [entry_body] => this is just UPDATED
        [status] => active
        [created_timestamp] => 2016-12-04 00:00:00
        [updated_timestamp] => 2017-01-03 00:00:00
        [id] => 2
        [comment] => This is another comments
        [blog_id] => 1
    )

 )
```

But, as you can see, there are MANY fields missing from the view because this is the SQL that was executed:

```
 SELECT  `entry`.`user_id` ,  `entry`.`entry_id` ,  `entry`.`entry_name` ,       
 `entry`.`entry_body` ,  `entry`.`status` , `entry`.`created_timestamp` ,  
 `entry`.`updated_timestamp` ,  `comments`.`id` ,  `comments`.`comment` , 
 `comments`.`user_id` ,  `comments`.`blog_id` ,  `comments`.`status` ,  
 `comments`.`created_timestamp` , `comments`.`updated_timestamp` 
 FROM  `entry` 
 LEFT JOIN  `comments` ON  `entry`.`entry_id` =  `comments`.`blog_id` 
 WHERE  `entry`.`entry_id` =1
```

Why are all the fields displaying?

Comment: exactly what you want from this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your select statement with this.

```
    $this->db->select('
    entry.user_id as euid,
    entry.entry_id,
    entry.entry_name,
    entry.entry_body,
    entry.status as entry_status ,
    entry.created_timestamp as entry_addtime,
    entry.updated_timestamp as entry_updatetime,
    comments.id as comments_id,
    comments.comment,
    comments.user_id as comments_userID,
    comments.blog_id,
    comments.status as comments_status,
    comments.created_timestamp as comments_addtime,
    comments.updated_timestamp as comments_addtime
');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have same column names in "entry" table as well as "comments" like user_id,status and etc.. which has same column name then the main table values will be returned. Just create alias for the matching columns liek below.

comments.user_id as cuser_id, comments.status as cstatus